# Eclipse AWS upload fuction to AWS lambda... is missing

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

My symptom is missing everything that exclude "Deploy serverless project" like this image.
I installed All of AWS toolkit, eclipse ADT and my eclipse version is oxygen[image]
I want to use "upload function to AWS lambda...", but it isn't show.....
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You have to select the individual class and select "Amazon Web Services" option. There you can choose to upload or run the lambda function. 
Please refer this link:
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/releases/tag/v201709262229

Comment: +1. I wish I seen this comment hours ago. Once you have the AWS toolkit and setup your IAM profile, then you should be good to go. Right-clicking on the root of the project will only show you the "Deploy Serverless Project..." and the other options are missing.

Half the reason I had the problem was due to the incorrect AWS documentation:

`Step 3: Upload your function

Under Project or Package Explorer View, right-click on your project and select Amazon Web Services -> Upload Function to AWS Lambda. `

Comment: Actually whats stated in the document works provided there is only one Lamdba function in a project. If you have multiple Lamdba function classes in the project then project level menu shows only "deploy serverless project".